# Реализация highlight

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно реализовать подсветку текста в `div` при вводе в `input` без использования сторонних плагинов. В существующем коде надо решить две проблемы:

1. При замене `html` перестают работать события на `<a class="hint">`, при этом элементы могут быть разные. Можно ли делать реинициализацию(?) после замены.
2. Как избежать замены в тэгах? Начните для примера вводить `class`.

Приветствуется лаконичное и легкое решение на `jQuery`/`JavaScript`.

```js
$(".hint").on("click", function() {
  alert('ok');
});

$("input").on("input", function() {

  var text = $(this).val();
  $('#text').html($('#text').html().replace(RegExp("(<highlight>|<\/highlight>)", "gi"), ''));

  if (!text) return;

  var re = $('#text').html().replace(RegExp("(" + text + ")", "gi"), '<highlight>$1</highlight>');
  $('#text').html(re);

});
```

```css
highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="search" placeholder="начните вводить текст" /><br/>
<div id="text">Съешь еще этих мягких <a class="hint">французских</a> булок</div>
```

Comment: `$(".hint").click` замените на `$("#text").on('click', "a.hint", function(){..})`

Comment: Я ответ дописал. Работающий :)

Answer (score 9):

На ответ не тянет, но так, информация к размышлению, возможно. Возьмите исходный html. Разбейте по тэгам. Сложите текст (исключая тэги), на места тэгов воткните какой-нибудь символ разделитель.
в поисковый шаблон между каждым символом вставьте необязательный этот разделитель, и замените регуляркой, обернув в `<highlight>`.
Замените разделитель обратно на тэги.

Описанное выше реализовано в коде ниже.

```js
$("#text, #result").on("click", ".hint", function() {
  alert('ok');
});

$("input").on("input", function() {
  console.clear()

  var text = $(this).val();
  var html = $("#text").html().split(/(<.*?>)/);
  
  var filtered = html.filter(function(v, idx){ return idx % 2 == 0; }).join("|");
  var x = text.split('').join("(\\|?)");  
    
  var re = new RegExp("(" + x + ")");
  var hl = filtered.replace(re, "<highlight>$1</highlight>");
    
  var z = -1;
  var result = hl.replace(/\|/g, () => html[z += 2] );
  $("#result").html(result);  
  
});
```

```css
highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="search" placeholder="начните вводить текст" /><br/>
<div id="text">Съешь еще этих мягких <a class="hint">французских</a> булок</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Оно даже в ФФ вроде подсвечивает, однако получаемый html будет не валидный,  например при вводе `их фр` вы получите

```
<highlight>их <a class="hint">фр</highlight>
```

поэтому требуется еще провести замену всех тэгов, которые найдены между `<highlight>` на  `</highlight><tag><highlight>`

Comment: решение плохо тем же, чем и в вопросе: используется `.html`, следовательно все обработчики установленные ранее надо будет устанавливать заново

Comment: @Grundy я так понял, что  в вопросе про обработчики имелось в виду в контексте класса `.hint` и не более, что решается через `.on()`. Но если в более широком смысле, то конечно, да, шляпа.

Comment: вообще кстати внедрение доп. тэгов может порушить css, в случае, если там использовались `>` правила

Comment: Не, не обязательно, если оборачивать только текстовые ноды

Comment: ко всему сайту такое лучше не применять)

Comment: @ThisMan еще бы :)

Comment: в вашем примере еще почему-то только первая буква подсвечивается, остальные нет ( допустим, ввести _е_ )

Comment: @ThisMan потому что регулярка замены без `g`, наверное

Comment: Браво лучшее решение

Answer (score 8):

Поиск любого текста, в том числе пересекающего различные элементы.

[image: скриншот]

Чтобы сильно не усложнять код, отформатировал html так, чтобы между блочными элементами был ровно один пробел. И вообще чтобы более одного пробела подряд не встречалось, иначе будет затруднительно угадать разметку при вводе поисковой строки.

```js
function getTextNodes(el) {
  return [...el.childNodes].flatMap(
    x => x.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE
       ? getTextNodes(x)
       : x.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ? [x] : []
  )
}

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var text = e.target.value;

  var container = document.querySelector(".search-content");

  for (var mark of container.querySelectorAll("mark")) {
    mark.outerHTML = mark.innerHTML;
  }
  
  if (!text) {
    return;
  }

  var mark = document.createElement('mark');
  mark.textContent = text;

  var nodes = getTextNodes(container)
  
  NODE: for (var q=0; q<nodes.length; ++q) {
    var node = nodes[q];
    var cur = node.nodeValue;
    var parts = cur.split(text);
    
    if (parts.length > 1) {
      var df = document.createDocumentFragment(), last;
      df.appendChild(document.createTextNode(parts[0]));
      
      for(var w=1; w<parts.length; ++w) {
        df.appendChild(mark.cloneNode(true));
        df.appendChild(last = document.createTextNode(parts[w]));
      }

      node.parentElement.replaceChild(df, node);
      node = last;
      cur = last.nodeValue;
    }
    
    for (var l=Math.min(text.length,cur.length+1); --l; ) {
      if (text.startsWith(cur.slice(-l))) {
        var p = l;
    
        for (var w=q+1; ; ++w) {
          cur = nodes[w].nodeValue;
          if (p + cur.length >= text.length) {
            break;
          } else if (text.slice(p).startsWith(cur)) {
            p += cur.length;
          } else {
            continue NODE;
          }
        }
        
        if (cur.startsWith(text.slice(p))) {
          var r = text.length - p;
          cur = node.nodeValue;
          
          var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
          df.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cur.slice(0, -l)));
          
          var m = document.createElement('mark');
          m.textContent = cur.slice(-l);
          df.appendChild(m);
          
          node.parentElement.replaceChild(df, node);
          
          while (++q < w) {
            var m = document.createElement('mark');
            nodes[q].parentElement.replaceChild(m, nodes[q]);
            m.appendChild(nodes[q]);
          }
          
          var df = document.createDocumentFragment();
          var m = document.createElement('mark');
          m.textContent = text.slice(p);
          df.appendChild(m);
          df.appendChild(last = document.createTextNode(nodes[w].nodeValue.slice(r)));
          
          nodes[w].parentElement.replaceChild(df, nodes[w]);
          nodes[w] = last;
          --q;
          
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input {
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 5px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 8px;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Введите текст для поиска">
<div class="search-content"><h1><i>Айзек Азимова</i>: <b>Конец вечности</b></h1> <div>Полный роман можно прочитать <a href="http://lib.ru/FOUNDATION/wechnost.txt_with-big-pictures.html">здесь</a></div> <p>Техник Эндрю Харлан вошел в капсулу. Капсула находилась внутри колодца, образованного редкими вертикальными прутьями. Прутья плотно облегали круглые стенки капсулы и, уходя вверх, терялись в непроницаемой дымке в шести футах над головой Харлана. Харлан повернул рукоятки управления и плавно нажал на пусковой рычаг. Капсула осталась неподвижной. Харлана это не удивило. Капсула не должна была двигаться ни вверх, ни вниз, ни вправо, ни влево, ни вперед, ни назад. Только промежутки между прутьями словно растаяли, затянувшись серой пеленой, которая была твердой, но все-таки нематериальной. Харлан почувствовал легкую дрожь в желудке и слабое головокружение и по этим признакам понял, что капсула со всем своим содержимым стремительно мчится в будущее сквозь Вечность. Он вошел в капсулу в 575-м Столетии. Этот Сектор Вечности стал его домом два года назад. Никогда до этого ему не приходилось забираться в будущее так далеко. Но сейчас он направляется в 2456-е Столетие. Месяц назад при одной только мысли об этом Харлану стало бы не по себе. Его родное 95-е Столетие осталось далеко в прошлом. Это был век патриархальных традиций, в котором атомная энергия находилась под запретом, а всем строительным материалам предпочитали дерево. Век славился своими напитками, которые в обмен на семена клевера вывозились почти во все другие Столетия. Хотя Эндрю Харлан не был дома с тех пор, как он в пятнадцать лет стал Учеником и прошел специальную подготовку, его никогда не оставляла тоска по родным Временам. Между 95-м и 2456-м Столетиями пролегло почти двести сорок тысяч лет, а это ощутимый промежуток даже для закаленного Вечного. При обычных обстоятельствах все было бы именно так. Однако сейчас Харлану было не до абстрактных размышлений. Рулоны перфолент оттягивали его карманы, планы тяжким грузом лежали на сердце, мысли были скованы страхом и неуверенностью. Он машинально остановил капсулу в нужном Столетии. Странно, что Техник способен волноваться.</p> Тестовый список для поиска <ul><li>Пункт 1</li> <li>Пункт 2</li> <li>Пункт 3</li> <li>Пункт 4 Подсписок <ul><li>Пункт 4.1</li> <li>Пункт 4.2</li> <li>Пункт 4.3</li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: можешь добавить описание алгоритма как это все у тебя работает? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, вроде примерно как у тебя?

Comment: Мне кажется у меня намного проще :-) словесное описание добавь хотя б

Comment: @Grundy, а словесное - это какое? И какие ещё есть варианты?

Comment: Это когда текстом со словами :-) еще можно графически показывать :-) видео и т.д. :-D

Answer (score 5):

Алгоритм такой:

1. получаем список всех дочерних элементов
2. идем по этому списку, если:

   21. это текстовый элемент `textNode`, то проверяем наличие `highlight`
   22. если это обычный элемент, то переходим к 1 пункту в контексте этого элемента

```js
class Highlight {
  constructor(input, content) {
    this.input_ = input;
    this.content_ = content;
    this.query_ = '';
    this.cache_ = [];

    this.init_();
  }

  // Проверяем является ли нода текстовой
  isTextNode_(node) {
    return node.nodeName === '#text';
  }
  
  // Проверяет, если совпадение в тексте
  hasMatch_(node) {
    return node.textContent.includes(this.query_);
  }

  highlightNodes_(element) {
    const children = element.childNodes; // children не подойдет, так как не возвращает textNode
    for(let child of children) {
      if(this.isTextNode_(child) && this.hasMatch_(child)) {
        this.highlightByQuery_(child);
      } else {
        this.highlightNodes_(child);
      }
    }
  }

  // Будет заниматься подсветкой
  highlightByQuery_(node) {
    const queryRegexp = new RegExp(this.query_, 'ig');
    // тут можно использовать html
    const markedNode = document.createElement('span');
    markedNode.innerHTML = node.textContent
      .replace(queryRegexp, str => `<mark>${str}</mark>`);
    node.replaceWith(markedNode);
    // Кешируем результат, что бы потом сбросить
    this.cache_.push(markedNode);
  }
  
  resetSearch_() {
    for(let node of this.cache_) {
      const regExp = /\<\/?mark\>/g;
      const content = node.innerHTML.replace(regExp, '');
      const textNode = document.createTextNode(content);
      node.replaceWith(textNode);
    }
    
    this.cache_ = [];
    this.query_ = '';
  }

  init_() {
    this.input_.onchange = this.search.bind(this);
  }

  search() {
    this.resetSearch_();
    this.query_ = this.input_.value;
    if(!this.query_.trim()) return;

    this.highlightNodes_(this.content_);
  }
}

// Собственно сам поиск
const content = document.querySelector('.search-content');
const queryInput = document.querySelector('input');

const highlight = new Highlight(queryInput, content);
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.controls {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

input {
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

button {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

mark {

}
```

```html
<div class='controls'>
  <input placeholder='Введите текст для поиска'/>
</div>
<div class='search-content'>
<h1><i>Айзек Азимова</i>: <b>Конец вечности</b></h1>
<div>
Полный роман можно прочитать <a href='http://lib.ru/FOUNDATION/wechnost.txt_with-big-pictures.html'>здесь</a>
</div>
<p>
 Техник Эндрю Харлан вошел в капсулу. Капсула находилась внутри колодца, образованного редкими вертикальными прутьями. Прутья плотно облегали круглые стенки капсулы и, уходя вверх, терялись в непроницаемой дымке в шести футах над головой Харлана. Харлан повернул рукоятки управления и плавно нажал на пусковой рычаг. Капсула осталась неподвижной. Харлана это не удивило. Капсула не должна была двигаться ни вверх, ни вниз, ни вправо, ни влево, ни вперед, ни назад. Только промежутки между прутьями словно растаяли, затянувшись серой пеленой, которая была твердой, но все-таки нематериальной. Харлан почувствовал легкую дрожь в желудке и слабое головокружение и по этим признакам понял, что капсула со всем своим содержимым стремительно мчится в будущее сквозь Вечность. Он вошел в капсулу в 575-м Столетии. Этот Сектор Вечности стал его домом два года назад. Никогда до этого ему не приходилось забираться в будущее так далеко. Но сейчас он направляется в 2456-е Столетие. Месяц назад при одной только мысли об этом Харлану стало бы не по себе. Его родное 95-е Столетие осталось далеко в прошлом. Это был век патриархальных традиций, в котором атомная энергия находилась под запретом, а всем строительным материалам предпочитали дерево. Век славился своими напитками, которые в обмен на семена клевера вывозились почти во все другие Столетия. Хотя Эндрю Харлан не был дома с тех пор, как он в пятнадцать лет стал Учеником и прошел специальную подготовку, его никогда не оставляла тоска по родным Временам. Между 95-м и 2456-м Столетиями пролегло почти двести сорок тысяч лет, а это ощутимый промежуток даже для закаленного Вечного. При обычных обстоятельствах все было бы именно так. Однако сейчас Харлану было не до абстрактных размышлений. Рулоны перфолент оттягивали его карманы, планы тяжким грузом лежали на сердце, мысли были скованы страхом и неуверенностью. Он машинально остановил капсулу в нужном Столетии. Странно, что Техник способен волноваться.
 </p>
 <ul>
  Тестовый список для поиска
  <li>
    Пункт 1
  </li>
   <li>
    Пункт 2
  </li>
   <li>
    Пункт 3
  </li>
   <li>
    Пункт 4
    <ul>
     Подсписок
        <li>
          Пункт 4.1
        </li>
        <li>
          Пункт 4.2
        </li>
        <li>
          Пункт 4.3
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**Плюсы:** не нужно беспокоиться про всякие обработчики, потому что работа идет с `textNode`, там ничего не повесить 
**Минусы:** если ввести *Запрос* c таким html: `<span>За</span>прос`, то не подсветит

Comment: наверное алгоритм примерно и должен быть такой (или даже только такой), но вот легким решение для себя я бы не назвал. Например почему просто так не работает когда вызываю <input placeholder='Введите текст для поиска' oninput='search()'/> ?

Comment: @Nsk можно и так сделать, к реализации подсветки этот уже не относится. Просто сделал так для красоты)

Comment: @Nsk теперь работает с `onchange`

Comment: @ThisMan, можно подход подобный [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/777704/186999) использовать

Comment: Здесь настоящие профессионалы

Comment: И вообще, экранированием даже не пахнет...

Comment: Точку попробуй поискать.

Answer (score 3):

Обработка текста содержащего html элементы в общем случае весьма не тривиальная задача. Так как то, что видит пользователь и то, как это отображено в разметке может разительно отличаться из-за стилей, и специальной работой с пробельными символами в браузере.

В данном случае можно использовать следующий алгоритм:

1. взять текстовое содержимое нужного элемента, это *примерно* текст, который видит пользователь.
2. найти в нем индексы подстрок, совпадающих с введенной строкой.
3. html-элементы можно представить в виде дерева, в котором в листовыми узлами являются текстовые элементы
4. исходя из пункта 3, обход дерева в глубину, позволит пройтись по всему тексту от начала до конца, попутно позволяя считать индексы каждого символа в результирующей строке
5. при обходе, можно собрать текстовые узлы, текст которых полностью либо частично входит в искомые индексы
6. теперь осталось пройтись по выбранным узлам и в соответствии с нужными индексами заменить в них куски строк, обернув их в нужный элемент, который можно подсветить.

---

Чтобы данный алгоритм можно было применять несколько раз - перед его применением нужно удалить элементы добавленные на прошлом ходу, чтобы устранить их дублирование.

Небольшой пример:

```js
$('.hint').click(function() {
  console.log(this.textContent)
});

function* deep(container) {
  // обход дерева в глубину
  for (var nodes = Array.from(container.childNodes); nodes.length;) {
    var node = nodes.shift();
    // если попался элемент - добавляем дочение узлы в начало проверки
    if (node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      nodes.unshift(...node.childNodes);
      continue;
    }
    // если попался текстовый узел - возвращаем
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
      yield node;
  }
}

// ищем в контейнере текстовые узлы, в которых полностью или частично расположены искомые строки
function find(container, entries) {
  var finded = [];
  var nodes = deep(container);
  var node = nodes.next().value;
  var curNodeStartIndex = 0;

  for (var entry of entries) { // для каждого интервала [startIndex, endIndex) соответствующего искомой строке
    while (curNodeStartIndex + node.textContent.length <= entry.startIndex) { // пропускаем узлы, пока не найдем узел, на который приходится startIndex
      curNodeStartIndex += node.textContent.length;
      node = nodes.next().value;
    }
    //сохраняем индекс символа в выбранном узле
    var start = entry.startIndex - curNodeStartIndex;

    while (curNodeStartIndex + node.textContent.length < entry.endIndex) { // добавляем в список новые узлы, пока не найдем узел, на который приходится endIndex
      curNodeStartIndex += node.textContent.length;
      finded.push({
        node,
        start: start - node.textContent.length,
        end: node.textContent.length
      });
      start = 0;
      node = nodes.next().value;
    }
    //сохраняем индекс символа в выбранном узле
    var end = entry.endIndex - curNodeStartIndex;

    finded.push({
      node,
      start: start - node.textContent.length,
      end: (end - node.textContent.length) || node.textContent.length
    });
  }

  return finded;
}

function highlight(container, textToFind, ignorecase) {
  var body = ignorecase ? container.textContent.toLowerCase() : container.textContent;
  textToFind = ignorecase ? textToFind.toLowerCase() : textToFind;
  // если передали пустую строку, либо общая длина текста меньше искомого фрагмента, то можно ничего не делать
  if (textToFind.length == 0 || body.length < textToFind.length) return;

  // ищем интервалы вхождений
  var points = []
  for (
    var findIndex = body.indexOf(textToFind, findIndex + 1); findIndex != -1; findIndex = body.indexOf(textToFind, findIndex + textToFind.length + 1)) {
    points.push({
      startIndex: findIndex,
      endIndex: findIndex + textToFind.length
    });
  }
  var nodes = find(container, points);

  // для каждого найденного узла вставляем в найденном месте элемент дял подсветки
  nodes.forEach(node => {
    var before = node.node.textContent.slice(0, node.start);
    var hl = document.createElement('mark');
    hl.textContent = node.node.textContent.slice(node.start, node.end);
    var after = node.node.textContent.slice(node.end);
    node.node.textContent = after;
    node.node.parentNode.insertBefore(hl, node.node);
    hl.insertAdjacentText('beforebegin', before);
  });
}

function removeHighlight(container) {
  // бежим по всем элементам подсветки и заменяем их текстовым содержимым
  for (hl of container.querySelectorAll('mark')) {
    hl.replaceWith(hl.textContent);
  }
  // сливаем все идущие подряд текстовые узлы в один.
  container.normalize();
}

(function($) {
  $.fn.highlight = function(options) {
    var defaultOptions = {
      text: '',
      ignorecase: true
    }
    options = $.extend(defaultOptions, options);
    return this.each(function() {
      removeHighlight(this);
      highlight(this, options.text, options.ignorecase);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$('input').on('input', function() {
  $('#text').highlight({
    text: this.value
  });
}).triggerHandler('input');
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  console.dir(this.value);
  $('#text2').highlight({
    text: this.value
  });
}).triggerHandler('input');
```

```css
.text {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

hl {
  background-color: yellow;
}

textarea {
  position: sticky;
  top: 8px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" placeholder="начните вводить текст" value="их" /><br/>
<div id="text">Съешь еще этих мягких <a class="hint">французских</a> булок</div>

<textarea rows="6">чности
  
    полный роман можно прочитать здесь
  
  
    техник</textarea>
<div id="text2">
  <h1><i>Айзек Азимова</i>: <b>Конец вечности</b></h1>
  <div>
    Полный роман можно прочитать <a href='http://lib.ru/FOUNDATION/wechnost.txt_with-big-pictures.html'>здесь</a>
  </div>
  <p>
    Техник Эндрю Харлан вошел в капсулу. Капсула находилась внутри колодца, образованного редкими вертикальными прутьями. Прутья плотно облегали круглые стенки капсулы и, уходя вверх, терялись в непроницаемой дымке в шести футах над головой Харлана. Харлан
    повернул рукоятки управления и плавно нажал на пусковой рычаг. Капсула осталась неподвижной. Харлана это не удивило. Капсула не должна была двигаться ни вверх, ни вниз, ни вправо, ни влево, ни вперед, ни назад. Только промежутки между прутьями словно
    растаяли, затянувшись серой пеленой, которая была твердой, но все-таки нематериальной. Харлан почувствовал легкую дрожь в желудке и слабое головокружение и по этим признакам понял, что капсула со всем своим содержимым стремительно мчится в будущее
    сквозь Вечность. Он вошел в капсулу в 575-м Столетии. Этот Сектор Вечности стал его домом два года назад. Никогда до этого ему не приходилось забираться в будущее так далеко. Но сейчас он направляется в 2456-е Столетие. Месяц назад при одной только
    мысли об этом Харлану стало бы не по себе. Его родное 95-е Столетие осталось далеко в прошлом. Это был век патриархальных традиций, в котором атомная энергия находилась под запретом, а всем строительным материалам предпочитали дерево. Век славился
    своими напитками, которые в обмен на семена клевера вывозились почти во все другие Столетия. Хотя Эндрю Харлан не был дома с тех пор, как он в пятнадцать лет стал Учеником и прошел специальную подготовку, его никогда не оставляла тоска по родным Временам.
    Между 95-м и 2456-м Столетиями пролегло почти двести сорок тысяч лет, а это ощутимый промежуток даже для закаленного Вечного. При обычных обстоятельствах все было бы именно так. Однако сейчас Харлану было не до абстрактных размышлений. Рулоны перфолент
    оттягивали его карманы, планы тяжким грузом лежали на сердце, мысли были скованы страхом и неуверенностью. Он машинально остановил капсулу в нужном Столетии. Странно, что Техник способен волноваться.
  </p>
  <ul>
    Тестовый список для поиска
    <li>
      Пункт 1
    </li>
    <li>
      Пункт 2
    </li>
    <li>
      Пункт 3
    </li>
    <li>
      Пункт 4
      <ul>
        Подсписок
        <li>
          Пункт 4.1
        </li>
        <li>
          Пункт 4.2
        </li>
        <li>
          Пункт 4.3
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: А я сделал - можно потестить)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, я тоже, в основном сделал :-) нужно немного доработать для переносов строк и объяснение написать :-)

Comment: Что за `hl`? Ну ведь [`mark`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/mark) же...

Comment: Да, вроде нормально. Разобрался :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, да это просто в вопросе был highlight я его сократил, лень было писать :-) про mark даж не слыша л:)

Answer (score 0):

Все же в мои сниппеты попал собственный код переписанный на JS. Проблему с тегами мне пожалуй проще решать на стороне сервера оборачивая чистый текст определенными тэгами, например span, и делая вызов навроде highlight('#text>span')

```
function highlight(s,e){
    var e=document.querySelectorAll(e);
    for ( var i=0; i<e.length; i++) { 
        e[i].innerHTML=e[i].innerHTML.replace(RegExp("(<highlight>|<\/highlight>)", "gi"), ''); // remove highlight
        if(s) e[i].innerHTML=e[i].innerHTML.replace(RegExp("("+s+ ")", "gi"), '<highlight>$1</highlight>'); // highlight
    }
}
```

с универсальными вариантами вызовов

```
<input type="text" oninput="highlight(this.value,'#text_div')"/>

<a onclick="highlight('Hello','#text_div')">highlight</a>
```