# Как сделать аналог поиска ctrl + f хрома для сайта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сделал поиск на сайте, но еще нужна функция чтобы можно было переключаться между найденными словами. Как сделать аналог поиска  ctrl + f  хрома для сайта?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
<input type="text" id="text-to-find" placeholder="Поиск" value=""> 
<input type="button" id="search-button" " onclick="javascript: FindOnPage('text-to-find'); return false;" value="Искать"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lastResFind=""; // последний удачный результат
  var copy_page=""; // копия страницы в ихсодном виде
  function TrimStr(s) {
       s = s.replace( /^\s+/g, '');
    return s.replace( /\s+$/g, '');
  }
  function FindOnPage(inputId) {//ищет текст на странице, в параметр передается ID поля для ввода
    var obj = window.document.getElementById(inputId);
    var textToFind;

    if (obj) {
      textToFind = TrimStr(obj.value);//обрезаем пробелы
    } else {
      alert("Введенная фраза не найдена");
      return;
    }
    if (textToFind == "") {
      alert("Вы ничего не ввели");
      return;
    }

    if(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(textToFind)=="0")
    alert("Ничего не найдено, проверьте правильность ввода!");

    if(copy_page.length>0)
          document.body.innerHTML=copy_page;
    else copy_page=document.body.innerHTML;


    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/name="+lastResFind+"/gi")," ");//стираем предыдущие якори для скрола
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(eval("/"+textToFind+"/gi"),"<a name="+textToFind+" style='background:#20b2aa;padding-top: 355px;margin-top: -355px;-webkit-background-clip: content-box;background-clip: content-box;'>"+textToFind+"</a>"); //Заменяем найденный текст ссылками с якорем;
    lastResFind=textToFind; // сохраняем фразу для поиска, чтобы в дальнейшем по ней стереть все ссылки
    window.location = '#'+textToFind;//перемещаем скрол к последнему найденному совпадению
   } 
</script>
```

Comment: зачем eval если есть конструктор принимающий строку?

Comment: При таком подходе реализации поиска у вас пропадут все события на странице.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919286/178988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный код это то, что я искал:

```
<div class="searchContend_h">
    <div class="ui-grid-c">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="textSearchvalue_h">
        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-b"> <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="searchButtonClickText_h">Search</a>

        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-c"> <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="next_h">Next</a>

        </div>
        <div class="ui-block-d"> <a href="#" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-inline="true" class="previous_h">Previous</a>

        </div>
        <div id="realTimeContents">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
            </div>
    </div>
</div>  
  function searchAndHighlight(searchTerm, selector) {
        if (searchTerm) {
            //var wholeWordOnly = new RegExp("\\g"+searchTerm+"\\g","ig"); //matches whole word only
            //var anyCharacter = new RegExp("\\g["+searchTerm+"]\\g","ig"); //matches any word with any of search chars characters
            var selector = selector || "#realTimeContents"; //use body as selector if none provided
            var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
            var matches = $(selector).text().match(searchTermRegEx);
            if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
                $('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted'); //Remove old search highlights  

                //Remove the previous matches
                $span = $('#realTimeContents span');
                $span.replaceWith($span.html());

        if (searchTerm === "&") {
            searchTerm = "&amp;";
            searchTermRegEx = new RegExp(searchTerm, "ig");
        }
                $(selector).html($(selector).html().replace(searchTermRegEx, "<span class='match'>" + searchTerm + "</span>"));
                $('.match:first').addClass('highlighted');

                var i = 0;

                $('.next_h').off('click').on('click', function () {
                    i++;

                    if (i >= $('.match').length) i = 0;

                    $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                    $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                    $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                    }, 300);
                });
                $('.previous_h').off('click').on('click', function () {

                    i--;

                    if (i < 0) i = $('.match').length - 1;

                    $('.match').removeClass('highlighted');
                    $('.match').eq(i).addClass('highlighted');
                    $('.ui-mobile-viewport').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('.match').eq(i).offset().top
                    }, 300);
                });

                if ($('.highlighted:first').length) { //if match found, scroll to where the first one appears
                    $(window).scrollTop($('.highlighted:first').position().top);
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.searchButtonClickText_h', function (event) {

        $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted").removeClass("match");
        if (!searchAndHighlight($('.textSearchvalue_h').val())) {
            alert("No results found");
        }
    });
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>


.highlighted {
     background-color:yellow;
 }
 .highlight {
     background-color: #fff34d;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     /* FF1+ */
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     /* Saf3-4 */
     border-radius: 5px;
     /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     /* FF3.5+ */
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
     box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     /* Opera 10.5+, IE 9.0 */
 }
 .highlight {
     padding:1px 4px;
     margin:0 -4px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется странным - почему вы меняете реальный контент страницы !?

Я бы реализовал это по другому:

1. можно найти все вхождения строки поиска в `nodeType === 3`
2. определить границы вхождений с помощью API Range
3. создать маску, которая перекрывает вхождения и не нарушает целостность реальной страницы

Конечно полная реализация заставит попотеть, но приведу рабочий пример.
Здесь не все реализовано, например нет установки свойств шрифта( увидите это при поиске в заголовке `h1` ) и т.п.

Запустите сниппет - должно быть как на этой картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');
document.getElementById('find').addEventListener('click', inputTextTrim);

// текущий текст поиска
var inputText;
var map = { /* inputText: массив_или_различные_опции */ };

function inputTextTrim() {
  var t = input.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  if (t && t !== inputText) {
    // для примера все удалю, но в реале такой объект можно использовать как кеш поиска
    if (map[inputText]) {
      while (map[inputText].length) {
        document.body.removeChild(map[inputText].pop());
      }
      map[inputText] = null;
      delete map[inputText];
    }
    inputText = t;
    console.log('find', inputText);
    findText(document.body /* root-element */);
  }
}

// Обход элементов
function findText(el) {
  [].forEach.call(el.childNodes, i => {
    // node 3 - текс
    if (i.nodeType === 3) {
      findTextNode(i);
    }
    else if (i.nodeType === 1) {
      findText(i);
    }
  });
}

// Поиск вхождения
function findTextNode(tn) {
  var t = tn.data.toLowerCase(), i = 0;
  // вхождений в строке может быть множество
  while ((i = t.indexOf(inputText, i)) !== -1) {
    selectText(tn, i++, inputText.length);
  }
}

// Поиск позиции
function selectText(tn, i, l) {
  console.log(tn, i, l);
  // копируем для наложения сверху
  var copy = tn.data.substring(i, i + l);
  if (!map[inputText]) {
    map[inputText] = [];
  }

  // определяем позицию и создаем элемент

  // выбираем наш кусок текста
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(tn, i);
  range.setEnd(tn, i + l);
  // определяем размеры и позиции
  var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  createFindText(inputText, copy, rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
}

// Создание элемента
function createFindText(iText, text, posX, posY, width, height) {
  var s = document.createElement('span');
  s.textContent = text;
  s.style.backgroundColor = '#FFEB3B';
  s.style.color = 'black';
  s.style.position = 'absolute';
  s.style.left = posX + 'px';
  s.style.top = posY + 'px';
  s.style.width = width + 'px';
  s.style.height = height + 'px';
  // для последующего удаления
  map[iText].push(s);
  document.body.appendChild(s);
}
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type='text' id='input'><input type='button' id='find' value='find'>
  <h1>Несколько элементов с текстом для поиска</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>1 element</li>
    <li>2 элемент</li>
    <li>наберите намеренно "элемент" для поиска слова "элемент" 4 раза</li>
  </ul>
  <span>English text</span>
</body>
```