# Получить «адрес» слова, то есть номер строки и отступ, внутри блока

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

У меня есть текст *одной строкой,* и мне надо узнать, на какой визуальной строке и на каком визуальном отступе от краёв будет находиться слово внутри блока. Например, когда «width» приблизительно равно 45 ch, мой текст отображается так:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua.
```

И «адрес» слова «labore» должен быть чем-то типа «3 строка, 14 ряд», а когда текст сверстался так:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua.
```

То «адрес» слова «labore» должен быть «2 строка, 42 ряд».

Comment: строка и ряд не синонимы в контексте матриц?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если искать в `DOM`, соответственно берете значение текстового узла

```js
var text = `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
et dolore magna aliqua.`;

var search = 'labore';

function searchPosition ( multiLine, search ) {
    var arrLine = multiLine.split( '\n' ), i;
    for ( var l = 0; l < arrLine.length; ++l ) {
        if ( ( i = arrLine[l].indexOf( search ) ) !== -1 ) {
            return { line: ++l, pos: i };
        }
    }
    return null;
}

console.log( searchPosition( text, search ) );
console.log( searchPosition( text, 'нет_слова' ) );
```

PS: Обновил для поиска в одной строке сжатого элемента `DIV`
Это очень простой вариант, с использованием только одного нормализованного `Node`.
Но может так оно и надо :)

```js
var textEl = document.getElementById( 'multiline' );

function searchPosition ( el, search ) {
    // Нормализуем
    el.normalize();
    var arrNode = el.childNodes, i, n, s;
    for ( i = 0; i < arrNode.length; ++i ) {
        if ( arrNode[i].nodeType === 3 ) {
            n = arrNode[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( !n || ( s = n.data.indexOf( search ) ) === -1 ) {
        return null;
    }

    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart( n, s );
    range.setEnd( n, ++s );
    // -1 на всякий случай, пиксель не имеет значения, 
    //    а на величину которую может отдать getBoundingClientRect, надеятся не стоит
    var top = range.getBoundingClientRect().top - 1;
    var rangeTop = document.createRange();
    rangeTop.setEnd( n, s );

    var pos = 0, rt, height;
   // Считаем символы
    while ( s-- ) {
        rangeTop.setStart( n, s );
        rt = rangeTop.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        if ( rt < top ) {
            height = ( top + 1 ) - rt;
            break;
        }
        ++pos;
    }
    
    // значит одна строка
    if ( !height ) {
        return { pos: pos, line: 1 };
    }
    
    // берем верх первого символа
    rangeTop.setStart( n, 0 );
    // подсчитываем строки
    var line = Math.floor( ( ( top + 1 ) - rangeTop.getBoundingClientRect().top + 1 ) / height );
    // если искомая строка не 1, то при поиске и переходе к верхней setStart захватит пробел,
    // вот этот самый пробел не войдет в getBoundingClientRect и будет лишний pos++
    return { pos: --pos, line: ++line };

}
console.log( searchPosition( textEl, 'Lorem' ) );
console.log( searchPosition( textEl, 'adipiscing' ) );
console.log( searchPosition( textEl, 'labore' ) );
console.log( searchPosition( textEl, 'нет_слова' ) );
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>multiline</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            #multiline {
                width: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='multiline'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: оптимизировал поиск строк

Comment: Вы не поняли. В оригинальном тексте нету `\n`, это одна строка. Мне нужно узнать позицию слова в зависимости от того, как текст сверстается; в зависимости от «width».

Comment: @Ainar-G, тогда надо было это отметить, но и это можно сотворить, только чуть сложнее

Comment: @Ainar-G, ну а так сойдет ?:)

Comment: Очень интересно. Не знал про «createRange» сотоварищи.

Comment: @Ainar-G, кстати вспомнил, что `getBoundingClientRect`, вроде не захватывает пробелы, поэтому поправил, иначе был не верный индекс при поиске в начале строки. Сейчас вроде нормально

Comment: Что-то жесть какая-то...

Comment: @Qwertiy, в чем жесть ?

Comment: А, посмотрел внимательнее. Ты просто в символы пересчитываешь. Что-то сомневаюсь, что автору это действительно нужно. Либо, при том, что он говорил про `ch`, у него моноширенный шрифт и тогда достаточно просто вычесть `left` родителя и разделить на ширину 1 символа. А вообще, всё ok.

Comment: @Qwertiy, про моноширенный шрифт я ничего не вижу. Но для примера не стал оптимизировать. Символы все-таки до начала линии нужно перебрать, а после можно расчитать высоту символов и расположение первого в Node, для вычисления всех строк.

Comment: Просто я не могу представить ситуацию, когда шрифт не моноширенный и номер символа в строке важнее его координат. Даже текстовые редакторы при переносе строк показывают позицию от перевода строки, а не от переноса.

Comment: Как в анекдоте [про отображение круга](http://www.mathforum.ru/forum/read/7/13667/)

Comment: @Qwertiy, про оптимизацию поиска строки, отметил выше в комменте. А вот к примеру в слове `Qwertiy` буква `Q` шире чем `i`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91761/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alexander-lonberg).

Answer (score 0):

При условии что в элементе находится просто текст одной нодой, можно получить расположение довольно легко. Если жее там насположен форматированный текст, то поиск [усложняется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919286/178988). Если слово может разрываться на 2 (или больше) прямоугольника, то следует использовать `getClientRects`. Вот реализация для простого случая:

```js
var p = document.querySelector("p"), text = p.textContent
var search = "dolore", i = text.indexOf(search), j = i + search.length

var r = document.createRange()
r.selectNodeContents(p.firstChild)
r.setStart(p.firstChild, i)
r.setEnd(p.firstChild, j)

console.log(r.getBoundingClientRect())
console.log(r.getClientRects())
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
aliqua.</p>
```