# js замена слова на всей странице

Tags: javascript, replace, find

Можно ли как-то улучшить код и написать все более эффективно?

Нужно заменить все определенные слова на странице и обнрнуть тегом...

```
document.body.innerHTML= document.body.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('word', 'g'), `<h1>глаголъ</h1>');
```

В данном коде есть сомнения, есть ли эффективным замена всего тела дока., вместо поиска по дереву и замена индивидуальной части. Если, например,

```
let matches = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("body *")).filter(el => el.textContent.includes('word'));
```

-- тогда если в тексте встречается тег, слово до тега будет заменено, после - нет. можно и с `.firstChild.nodeValue` уточнать, но мало что меняет. Что странно, при поиске с `el.firstChild.nodeValue.includes('word');`, если в теге есть, например, `<h3>2contain word<span>на wordывоаывол</span>word certin text</h3>` span, тогда за ним результат наличия условия уже пробускается, а берется h3 до спана и сам спан, как результаты...

Имеет ли смысл использовать `substring` ?

обновл: значит, проблема главная в том, что бы вставить html и не обрушить события: `el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(хWord,`${хWord}`)`

можно ли взять Node и его value и вставить html в текст как-то?

(в комментах есть ссылки на алгоритмы, но ищу что-то явно проще... как-то vue.js и др. ведь это дело делают)

Comment: В первом варианте у вас слетят все события. Во втором варианте слово вообще не меняется.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо, если события летят - тогда не могу пользовать тот способ. А во втором потом через matches.forEach( меняю как в первом случае. Наверно, нужно найти начало/конец позиции найденного слова и вставить новое? ...если так- как?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Ладно бы только события. Если искомое слово будет, например, "div", то все станет еще интереснее.

Comment: Опять же, смотря, как будете менять. Если опять через `innerHTML` - то опять же слетят события. К тому же, возможны варианты вида `<span>При<b>вет</b></span>`. Нужно ли заменить слово **Привет**?

Comment: И опять же, добавлю, бывает и вовсе такое: `<span>При<b></b>вет</span>`, лично когда-то наблюдал подобные артефакты в HTML, сгенерированном из MS Word.

Comment: @Yaant вы читаете мои мысли? о_О А вообще задача не такая тривиальная, как могло бы показаться. Поищите, где-то был более-менее хороший ответ на ruSO.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Нет, не читаю, это был уже комментарий к Вашему примеру с "Привет" :)

Comment: [похожая задача](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/914683/186999), возможно даже дубликат

Comment: Как вам уже подсказали, замена через `innerHTML` - плохая идея. Лучше всего делать замену внутри каждого `textNode`. @Grundy выше дал ссылку на пост, там можно найти примеры решений, но у меня есть к ним замечание. Как по мне, обход текстовых нодов вручную - устаревший вариант. Сейчас есть интерфейс [`TreeWalker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker), он проще и эффективнее ручного обхода. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579869/) есть сравнение различных способов получения `textNodes`, в т.ч. `TreeWalker`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369978

кажется, нашел идеальный вариант

```
const highlightWord = 'is';

function highlight(element, regex) {
    const document = element.ownerDocument;

    let getNodes = function() {
        let nodes = [],
            offset = 0,
            node,
            nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(element, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, null, false);

        while (node = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
            nodes.push({
                textNode: node,
                start: offset,
                length: node.nodeValue.length
            });
            offset += node.nodeValue.length
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    let nodes = getNodes(this.nodes);
    if (!nodes.length) return;

    let text = '';
    for (let node of nodes)
        text += node.textNode.nodeValue;

    let match;
    while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
        // Prevent empty matches causing infinite loops
        if (!match[0].length) {
            regex.lastIndex++;
            continue;
        }

        // Find the start and end text node
        let startNode = null, endNode = null;
        for (let node of nodes) {
            if (node.start + node.length <= match.index) continue;
            if (!startNode) startNode = node;
            if (node.start + node.length >= match.index + match[0].length) { endNode = node; break; }
        }

        let range = document.createRange();
        range.setStart(startNode.textNode, match.index - startNode.start);
        range.setEnd(endNode.textNode, match.index + match[0].length - endNode.start);

        let spanNode = document.createElement('u');

        spanNode.appendChild(range.extractContents());
        range.insertNode(spanNode);

        nodes = getNodes();
    }
}

const testDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let originalHtml = testDiv.innerHTML;
(_ => {
    testDiv.innerHTML = originalHtml;
    highlight(testDiv, new RegExp(highlightWord, 'g'));
})()
```