# Сопоставление текста и html. Поиск позиции

Tags: javascript, дискретная-математика

Есть текст и его html версия:

> Once upon a time there was a very rich man who lived with his three daughters.  The two older daughters laughed at anyone who did not dress as wel as they did.  If the two of them were not resting at home, they were out shopping for as many fine dresses and hats as they could carry home.

```
<span>
        <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
            <p class="p1" style="margin: 0px; font: 17px; font-family: Helvetica Neue"><b>Once upon a time there was
                    a
                    very rich man who <span style="color: blue">lived</span> with his three daughters.<span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;
                    </span>The two older daughters laughed at anyone who di<span style="color: orange">d n</span>ot dress <span style="color: green">as</span> wel as they did.<span
                        class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp; </span>If the two of them were not resting at home,
                    they were out shopping for as many fine dresses and hats as they could <span style="color: red">carry</span> home. <span
                        class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span></b></p><br>
        </div>
        <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
        </div>
    </span>
```

Нужно универсальное решение, чтобы находить позицию слова/фразы из текста в html
Проблема в том, что в слове/фразе может находится какой-либо стиль

```
di<span style="color: orange">d n</span>ot
```

что затрудняет поиск

Пытался прослушивать сдвиги с помощью расстояния Левенштейна, но это очень "тяжелое" решение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Реализация highlight](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914683/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-highlight)

Comment: @UModeL нет, но похоже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел кривое, но все же решение

```js
let html = document.getElementById('input').innerHTML;
let word = 'did not';

console.log(searchPositions(html, word));

function searchPositions(html, issueText) {
    let htmlArr = Array.from(html).map((item, index) => {
        return {
            item,
            index
        }
    });

    const regexp = /<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g;
    const tags = html.match(regexp) || [];
    const textTrue = html.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '');

    let inTextStartPosition = textTrue.indexOf(issueText);
    let inTextEndPosition = inTextStartPosition + issueText.length - 1;

    let matches = [...html.matchAll(regexp)];
    let tagsIndexs = matches.map((item) => {
        return item.index;
    });

    let tagsInfo = tags.map((item, index) => {
        let length = item.length;
        let startPosition = tagsIndexs[index];
        let endPosition = startPosition + length;

        return {
            startPosition,
            endPosition,
            length
        }
    })

    for (let ii = 0; ii < tagsInfo.length; ii++) {
        let startPosition = tagsInfo[ii].startPosition;
        let endPosition = tagsInfo[ii].endPosition;

        while (startPosition !== endPosition) {
            htmlArr = htmlArr.filter(x => x.index !== startPosition);
            startPosition++;
        }
    }

    let start = htmlArr[inTextStartPosition].index;
    let end = htmlArr[inTextEndPosition].index;

    return {
        start,
        end
    }
}
```

```html
<div id='input'>
        <span>
            <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
                <p class="p1" style="margin: 0px; font: 17px; font-family: Helvetica Neue"><b>Once upon a time there was
                        a
                        very rich man who <span style="color: blue">lived</span> with his three daughters.<span
                            class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;
                        </span>The two older daughters laughed at anyone who di<span style="color: orange">d n</span>ot
                        dress <span style="color: green">as</span> wel as they did.<span
                            class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp; </span>If the two of them were not resting at home,
                        they were out shopping for as many fine dresses and hats as they could <span
                            style="color: red">carry</span> home. <span class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span></b>
                </p><br>
            </div>
            <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

js file:

```js
const text = document.querySelector('.p1')
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const output = document.querySelector('output');

let fullText = text.textContent.split('<span>')[0].split('');

for (let i = 0; i < fullText.length; i++) {

    if (fullText[i] === ' ' || fullText[i] === '\n') {
        if (fullText[i + 1] === ' ' || fullText[i + 1] === '\n') {
            fullText.splice(i, 1)
            i--;
        }
    }
}

fullText = fullText.join('').split(' ');

console.log(fullText)

input.addEventListener('input', ({target}) => {
    console.log(Boolean(target.value))
    if (target.value) {
        if (target.value.split(' ').length > 1) {
            // console.log(~fullText.join(' ').indexOf(target.value))
            if (~fullText.join(' ').indexOf(target.value)) {
                output.textContent = target.value
            } else {
                output.textContent = 'not found'
            }
        } else {
            let all = ''
            fullText.forEach((e) => {
                if (~e.indexOf(target.value)) {
                    console.log(e);
                    all += `${e} `
                }
            })
            output.textContent = all
        }
    }

})
```

html:

```html
<input type="text">
<output></output>

<span>
        <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
            <p class="p1" style="margin: 0px; font: 17px; font-family: Helvetica Neue"><b>Once upon a time there was
                    a
                    very rich man who <span style="color: blue">lived</span> with his three daughters.<span
                        class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;
                    </span>The two older daughters laughed at anyone who di<span style="color: orange">d n</span>ot dress <span
                        style="color: green">as</span> wel as they did.<span
                        class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp; </span>If the two of them were not resting at home,
                    they were out shopping for as many fine dresses and hats as they could <span style="color: red">carry</span> home. <span
                        class="Apple-converted-space">&nbsp;</span></b></p><br>
        </div>
        <div style="font-family:Calibri,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12pt; color:rgb(0,0,0)">
        </div>
    </span>
```

Comment: если вам что-либо не понятно - спрашивайте

Comment: если искать did not, то он его не находит

Comment: @grvctr я переписал решение посмотрите