# как подсветить в тексте слово которое начинается на @ ? к примеру чтобы @auto , @name имели определенный цвет

Tags: javascript, css

как подсветить в тексте слово которое начинается на @ ? к примеру чтобы @auto , @name имели определенный цвет

то слово может быть может нет появляется динамически с сервера приходит текст

Comment: Автоматически оборачивать ваши спец слова в определенные теги с классами или ещё более с гиперссылками и прочим.благо js это позволяет

Comment: @Aziz Umarov пример можно?

Comment: Junior пример можно?

Comment: возможно это поможет https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914683/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-highlight/914860#914860 но если у вас просто какой-то фрагмент текста в котором надо замену сделать, а не поиск всего на странице, то тут действительно все просто будет.  Уточните задачу - откуда берется текст?

Comment: @teran это комментарий когда комментируют в форму вставляются имя участника и так записывается в базу, а когда публикуются на странице переменная выводить весь этот текст нужно чтобы если было в тексте слово "@name" добавить ему тег

Comment: если это обычный текст без разметки, то регулярные выражения в помощь.