# Код для подсвечивания букв почему-то работает не так

Tags: javascript

Есть код для поиска по странице, но подсветка слов не работает, оно дублирует весь текст

```js
document.querySelector('#elastic').oninput = function() {
  let val = this.value.trim().toLowerCase();
  let elasticItem = document.querySelectorAll('.elastic div');

  if (val != '') {

    elasticItem.forEach(function(elem) {
      if (elem.innerText.toLowerCase().search(val) == -1) {
        elem.classList.add('hide');
        elem.innerHTML = elem.innerText;
      } else {
        elem.classList.remove('hide');
        let str = elem.innerText;
        elem.innerHTML = inserMark(str, elem.innerText.search(val), val.length);
      }
    });
  } else {
    elasticItem.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.classList.remove('hide');
      elem.innerHTML = elem.innerText;

    });
  }
}

function inserMark(stra, pos, len) {
  return stra.slice(0, pos) + '<mark>' + stra.slice(pos, pos + len) + '</mark>' + stra.slice(pos + len)
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search1">
  <input type="text" id="elastic" placeholder="Search FAQ">
</div>

<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <p>ORDER</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Can I return all or part of my order?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod

  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Is there a limit to how much I can order online? Why did I receive an order max error notification?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel">
    To properly manage inventory for all online customers, an order quantity limit of 1/2 pallet per item, and re-order frequency of 15 days has been set for online orders. If customers are able to order items in full pallet quantities, please contact us
    regarding moving to direct service.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="elastic">
  <div class="accordion">
    <p>Can I return all or part of my order?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="panel">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/914683/223826 было что-то на на тему подсветки

Comment: Вместо elem.innerHTML = inserMark(str, elem.innerText.search(val), val.length);  надо elem.innerHTML = inserMark(str, elem.innerText.toLowerCase().search(val), val.length);

Comment: теперь оно не клолнирует текст а ставит пробелы, то убирает их, оно и до этого так делало, не знаете как это исправить?