# Как работает поиск по странице в браузерах?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, google-chrome, search

Конкретно интересует то, как они находят и **выделяют** совпадения, когда поисковой запрос на самой странице может быть разделён тегами. Например они легко могут найти `lorem ipsum` в строке `lorem <i>ipsum</i>`.

Какой там принцип?

Comment: Они ищут не по html, а по обычному тексту, который видит обычный пользователь

Comment: Но нельзя просто взять текст и выделить его на странице, не найдя его в html (и не выделив тегами). Из-за возможного присутствия тегов просто найти "текст" в html может не получится.

Comment: Почему нельзя? Вот вы сейчас видите текст не находя его в html, разве нет?

Comment: Там всё ваще не просто и учитывается куча всего. Вплоть до того что, например, Яндекс. Браузер умеет искать разные формы слов.

Comment: вспомнился аж вопрос старый https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/914683/223826

Answer (score 0):

Ответить на твой вопрос можно например вот так

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p id="outer">My first <span>paragraph</span>.</p>

<script>
document.write(outer.innerText)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

А если без стеба, то естественно DOM знает как выглядит текст без вложенности и тэгов. Это всего лишь фильтры