Обертка тегом одинаковых в тексте слов, буквы которых имеют разные регистры, с помощью регулярных выражений
Есть инпут, при вводе какого-то слова или буквы, которые встречаются несколько раз в тексте, эти повторения будут выделены тегом mark. Я нахожу одинаковые слова с помощью регулярного выражения, а потом заменяю их с помощью метода replace(). Однако при таком раскладе все буквы будут маленькие, так как на замену идет буква, которая была в инпуте. И соответственно, все повторяющиеся буквы большого регистра (или одинаковые слова, начинающиеся с большой буквы) будут заменены на те же буквы, но с маленьким регистром. Как сделать так, чтобы регистры букв при замене соответствовали изначальным регистрам?
const text = document.querySelector('.text');

const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let value = input.value
    words(text, value)
    
})

function words(text, search) {
    let words = text.textContent
    if (words.indexOf(`${search}`) != -1 && search != '' && search != ' ') {
        let searchAll = new RegExp(search, 'gi')
        let newText = words.replace(searchAll, '<mark>' + search + '</mark>')
        text.innerHTML = newText
    } else {
         console.log('did not find');
    }
}

    


Это ищете?

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/919286/178988

Зачем indexOf, когда есть test ? Думаю, что в этом месте была проблема.


const text = document.querySelector('.text');
const input = document.querySelector('.input');

input.addEventListener('input', words);

function words() {
  let search = this.value;
  let newText = text.textContent;
  let rExp = new RegExp(`(${search})`, 'gi');
  if (rExp.test(`${newText}`) && search) {
    text.innerHTML = newText.replace(rExp, '<mark>$1</mark>');
  } else {
    console.log('did not find');
    text.innerHTML = newText;
  }
}
<input class="input">
<p class="text">Есть инпут, при вводе какого-то слова или буквы, которые встречаются несколько раз в тексте, эти повторения будут выделены тегом mark. Я нахожу одинаковые слова с помощью регулярного выражения, а потом заменяю их с помощью метода replace().</p>




За запихивание ввода пользователя напрямую в регулярку надо руки отрывать ;)

@Qwertiy, ну-ну, полно Вам. Здесь же показан сам принцип. А безопасность - это уже другой вопрос ;)

@Qwertiy, а как тогда можно обезопасить ввод? Проблема может быть в том, что пользователь может ввести код (например, "")? Или это вообще не то?

@Bemfes, не беспокойтесь - для конкретного скрипта это не критично, так как Вы производите манипуляции с DOM на клиенте, не касаясь серверной стороны. Да и тут больше не про безопасность, а про корректность вводимого (типа экранирование спецсимволов и т.п.)

@UModeL, хорошо, спасибо!

@Bemfes, это ж конструктор регулярки, а не eval даже - тут инъекции, которые позволят что-то зловредное сделать маловероятны. Но можно ввести точку и получить неправильный результат, или ввести скобку и уронить весь скрипт с ошибкой, а если это на каком-нибудь фреймвёрке вытворить, то есть шансы получить просто пустую белую страницу вместо сайта. Да, надо экранировать спецсимволы перед помещением пользовательского ввода в регулярку.

@UModeL, делаем приложение на реакте без error boundary, пользователь вводит в инпут скобку и получает белый экран. С error boundary чуть лучше, но страница с "ой, что-то пошло не так" - это немного не то, что хотел пользователь.

@Bemfes, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1595532/178988.
